# Filter Google search results to keyword appearing in subdomain or domain itself

Tags: google-search

While I'm aware that an `allindomain` operator doesn't exist, I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to achieve this with `allinurl` or similar in Google Search.

`allinurl:` returns results containing the specified keyword anywhere within the URL (directories, sub-directors, domain name, etc.).

I'm trying to limit results to those containing the keyword either in a subdomain (http://keyword.example.com) or just the domain itself (http://examplekeyword.com)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, this can be achieved using quotes and wildcards. So something along the lines of searching `"http://*keyword*.*"` for a domain or `"http://*keyword*.example.com"` for a sub-domain of example.com.

You could simply use `"http://*keyword*"` to get as comprehensive results as possible.

(For completeness' sake, you must include the quotation marks, they limit it to `"exactly this phase"` while the asterisks can represent a character or number of characters.)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `site:` parameter in the Google Search to your advantage in this case.

Lets say you want to find the word "Magic" in any website within the `stackexchange.com` domain, simply type in "Magic site:stackexchange.com" and it would bring up search results that is isolated to the domains and subdomains of stackexchange.com.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

allintitle:"________"

intitle:"___________"

allinurl:"__________"

inurl:"_____________"

Measure how many websites (competitors) are using the keyword (you want to rank for on google) by searching google using the above techniques, use it in your website after and therefore Force google to show your website within the first 100 results. That does not guarantee any type of ranking on the first page.

User experience will for sure determine ranking on the Google's organic top results.

Do not click on any of the hyperlinks it's all hacked (Viruses)
Search Google for
To get the number of websites that are using the exact key phrase

allintitle:"________"
intitle:"_____"
allinurl:"____________"
inurl:"____"
And what's cool, that you search two at the same time for example;

inurl: .org/resources intitle: london gym

No alt text provided for this image
The results now will only include websites that has .org/resources and related London gym quires.

You are probably wondering where is the Free keyword tools. Well, all the hyperlinks are the free tools.

Cheers!
My original article
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/google-research-hacks-101-plus-000-cost-tools-you01r-ammar/

https://aisocal.com/